# Tinymce toolbar buttons have no text inside. Accessibility audit Error

Tags: javascript, tinymce, accessibility, screen-readers

Tinymce toolbar buttons have no text inside. Only the respective icons are present.

Accessibility audit tools like WAVE can't seem to get over this. How do we add hidden text to the buttons?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Each button in the toolbar should have an `aria-label` property at the root of the element that describes the purpose of the button.

[image: Here's what the Bold button's label looks like.]